# Responsive sprite sheet animation not scaling well

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I am trying to animate a sprite sheet and to allow it to be responsive. I have the animation working, however when I scale it down the animation becomes shaky and the image repeats itself on the top (very slightly, probably 1 or 2 pxs worth)

The fiddle can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/gag847kp/2/

To replicate the issue change the scale to something less than 1, like .8

The proportions of the div's width/height to the sprite sheet width/height seem fine, I am not sure what is causing the problem. Example, the image is originally 250x241. When I scale it too .8, it becomes 200x192.8, both of a ratio of 1.037344398340249.

Likewise, the div's background-size is consistent, width of 200 and height of 4820 when scaled. (Their are 25 frames, each frame a height of 192.8 = 4820)

The actual sprite sheet re-sizing code:

```
function resizeAnimations() {
    $.each(animations, function(index, animation) {
        resize(animation.$ele);

        var width = animation.originalWidth * scale;
        var height = (animation.originalHeight *  animation.animation.frames) * scale;

        animation.$ele.css('background-size', width + "px " + height + "px");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into a ***sub-pixel*** issue for your (resized) animated sprite due to floated number.

*Floor* the result value: ***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0twovu8x/)***

```
var sprite_height_scaled = (animation.originalHeight * scale) << 0;
```

(the above `<<` is the fastest one; you can also use one of this:)

```
(animation.originalHeight * scale) | 0
```

```
parseInt(animation.originalHeight * scale, 10)
```

```
Math.floor(animation.originalHeight * scale, 10)
```

If it still appears here's another aspect of the issue:*

```
// 25(frames) / 6025px(sprite-height) = 241px frame height
// now let's scale
var scale = 0.8;
console.log( (6025/25)*scale );     // 168.7px
// We cannot have subpixel values so let's floor the result:
console.log( (6025/25)*scale | 0 ); // 168px
// Still, the main problem is: if we resize the background to 0.8 scale,
// will every frame's first pixel line inherit the 
// previous frame (lower line) sub-pixel data?
// Most likely.
```

Than simply open your sprite in your editor and add `2 * expected-min-scale (round to even)` transparent pixels between every frame.

Comment: Add Math.floor() to every value that changes the dom, still having the issue. Updated fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/gag847kp/4/

Comment: Without editing the sprite sheet, I first calculated the whole number height of the (animation height * scale) and used that number as a reference to scale off of. If anyone is having the same issue the updated fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/gag847kp/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try rounding down the calculated resize dimensions.

```
function resize($ele) {
    $ele
        .height(Math.floor($ele.height() * scale))
        .width(Math.floor($ele.width() * scale));
}
```

I think the natural behaviour is `.round()`.

I truth, you can't win as in other circumstances maybe `.ceil()` might be better than `.floor()`.

A better solution would be to give your sprite frames greater margins.